# Eclipse: does not launch the app after installing .apk (android)

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

Recently after having updated lots of stuff on android SDK something happened to Eclipse.

I'm running the apps on an actual device instead of an emulator. Before the updates, after I used to click 'Run' and select my device, it would upload the .apk to the phone and immediately launch the app. For some reason, it doesn't do that anymore and simply stops after installing:

```
[2011-11-09 18:17:18 - helloworld] Android Launch!
[2011-11-09 18:17:18 - helloworld] adb is running normally.
[2011-11-09 18:17:18 - helloworld] Performing com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid     activity launch
[2011-11-09 18:17:26 - helloworld] Device API version is 10 (Android 2.3.6)
[2011-11-09 18:17:26 - helloworld] Uploading helloworld.apk onto device '363294A87A1000EC'
[2011-11-09 18:17:26 - helloworld] Installing helloworld.apk...
```

The phone is on debugging mode and I generally haven't changed anything on Eclipse's settings - it literally stopped working after the SDK updates. Any idea how to make it automatically run the apps again?

Thanks

Comment: are you out of memory on the device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sorry for my bad english. I had the same problem after sdk updates. To solve this problem you have to update also "Android DDMS", "ADT" and all other components on eclipse. To do this open eclipse and click on "Help -> Check for updates". All android parts in eclipse will update automatically to the latest version (the version of SDK). I hope that this will work also for you. Bye.

Matteo

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I did miss a few updates for Eclipse. Works like a charm now, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Make sure these are in your manifest in the intent filter for your activity.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, **Right click on Project > Runs As > Run Configurations >** select **Launch Default Activity** under Android Tab.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your "Run Configurations under the project context menu. Right click on your project and choose "Run As -> Run Configurations". Choose target tab and choose "Manual" for deployment Target Selection Mode. This will allow you to see what Eclipse should see when it is looking for a target. If your phone doesn't show, then you may have to configure something else.

You did not mention phone type.

Also verify your original Virtual Devices are still in AVD.

Comment: It is set to manual and I do get to pick a device to run the app on - there are two virtual devices and my android phone (Nexus S, 2.3.6). After doubleclicking the phone, I again get the logs saying "Uploading..." and "Installing...", but the phone does absolutely nothing. In fact, after having deleted the app from the phone, it does not even seem to install anymore at all (doesn't show up in settings -> manage applications).